# Проблема с кодировкой при записи в базу данных Bugzilla из хука svn

Tags: perl

Пытаюсь связать svn и bugzilla (4.0). Для создания комментария изменил svn_bz_append.pl, так как в Bugzilla (4.0) нет AppendComment. Вставил такие строки:

```
foreach my $bug (@bugs)
{
     my $sth =  Bugzilla->dbh->prepare("insert into longdescs (bug_id, who, bug_when, work_time,thetext, isprivate, already_wrapped, type) values ( $bug, $userid, now() ,0,'$message',0,0,0)");
     $sth->execute;    
}
```

Запись вставляется, однако русские символы в абракадабре. База Bugzilla в utf-8  кодировке в Pg. Пытался использовать `encode("utf-8",$message)` но результат такой же.
Как решить проблему с кодировкой?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема закрыта. `svn_bz_append.pl` и `post-commit` должны быть в UTF-8 и в `post-commit` нужно добавить `export LANG=ru_RU.UTF-8`.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте конвертнуть $message с помощью модуля [Encode](http://search.cpan.org/~dankogai/Encode-2.44/Encode.pm).

```
use Encode 'from_to';    
from_to($message, 'cp1250', 'utf8');
```

Существуют еще другие модули: [Text::Iconv](http://search.cpan.org/~mpiotr/Text-Iconv-1.7/Iconv.pm) и [Convert::Cyrillic](http://search.cpan.org/~jneystadt/cyrillic-1.05/Convert/Cyrillic.pm)

Comment: пробовал from_to: не помогает.

Comment: вот что пишется в базу:
"/svndata/projects rev 87 committed by user1
bug 1 ?\208?\183?\208?\176?\208?\191?\208?\184?\209?\129?\209?\140 ?\208?\184?\208?\183 SVN

http://bug.head.imsgroup.ru/projects?view=rev&revision=87 

U   RFPS/src/com/experian/rfps/Searcher.java
"

Мне кажется, что сообщение уже кривое перед добавлением базу.

Answer (score 0):

А сам Pg на UTF8 настроен? Вообще, может нужен decode, а не encode? :) А так смотрите [perlunicode](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlunicode.html).

Answer (score 0):

Пробывали добавлять прагму
use utf8